# Show the validation message when user selects a field

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, forms, validation

I have a simple ASP.NET MVC form, everything work fine, the only thing is I want to 
automatically show the validation message when I selects a field. But to show the message validation I need to send the form. Do I need to use ajax ? thanks for your help.

Here is my form :

```
    @using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, new { id = "TestForm" }))
    {
          <div>
             @Html.LabelFor(m => m.FirstName)
          </div>

          <div>
             @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FirstName, new { id = "FirstName" })
             @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.FirstName)
           </div>
           <div>
              @Html.LabelFor(m => m.LastName)
           </div>

           <div>
             @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.LastName, new { id = "LastName" })
             @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.LastName)
           </div>

            ...

}
```

Model

```
    public class TestModel
        {
            [Required(ErrorMessage = "FirstName should blabla")]
            [StringLength(4, ErrorMessage = "You must...", MinimumLength = 1)]
            [DataType(DataType.Text)]
            [Display(Name = "FirstName")]
            public string FirstName { get; set; }

            [Required(ErrorMessage = "LastName should blabla")]
            [StringLength(4, ErrorMessage = "You must...", MinimumLength = 1)]
            [DataType(DataType.Text)]
            [Display(Name = "LastName")]
            public string LastName { get; set; }

            ...
}
```

Comment: You can write a bit of javascript to trigger an unobtrussive validation on the event of field selection. There is plenty other questions/articles on how you can do it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need to take steps to enable client-side validation. [This blog post](http://www.jacopretorius.net/2011/01/client-side-validation-in-mvc-3.html) talks about using the built-in validators. You'll need `@{ Html.EnableClientValidation(); }` before the `Html.BeginForm` call, or you can do it in the Web.config.

[This VS Magazine article](http://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2012/04/09/adding-client-side-validation-in-asp.net-mvc-3.aspx) discusses the process of registering a JavaScript function and a server-side method to answer the JavaScript request. Though it was written for MVC 3, it should apply equally well to MVC 4.

Comment: thanks for your help, but when I try to access your VS magazine article I get a 404 error page. Do you have an example of code using ajax ?

Comment: A Google search provided a number of promising links if you need more specific examples, such as [MVC3 Custom Client Side Validation with Unobtrusive Ajax](http://www.falconwebtech.com/post/2012/04/21/MVC3-Custom-Client-Side-Validation-with-Unobtrusive-Ajax.aspx)